# Transpose Multidimensional Table

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently parsing my way through a large set of PDF's and extracting a list of Hardware Address based on which  module they belong too. The idea is to construct a dependency diagram which will aid any future reversing of code. 
Due to the very large nature of the problem, I'm using the pandas as the main Database API as its very easy to apply function to column.

The Database
The Database comprises of two fields, namely the Address and Module Name (see below).
Where each record details the membership of a single (and unique) address with respect the modules its a member of. The Associate Modules field is of type List and can have a varying number of elements. However Address with only have one value.

Problem
Ideally using the optimized Pandas API, how can I transform the below "RawTable" into
the "Dependency Table"? Code example are much appreciated.

```
<Current Database>
xxxxx*[Pandas::RawTable]******
* Address * Associate Modules *
******************************
*   1000  * ["1A","2A","3A"] *
*   1001  * ["2A","4A","5A"] *
*   1002  *   ["1A", "4A"]   *
******************************

<Future Database>
******[Pandas:: DependencyTable****
* Associate Modules *   Address   *
***********************************
*     "1A"         *     1000     *
*     "1A"         *     1002     *
*     "2A"         *     1000     *
*     "2A"         *     1001     *
*     "3A"         *     1000     *
*     "4A"         *     1001     *
*     "4A"         *     1002     *
*     "5A"         *     1001     *
***********************************
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like modules are loaded as a column of lists.

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(
        {'Address': [1000, 1001, 1002],
        'Associate Modules': [['1A', '2A', '3A'],
                              ['2A', '4A', '5A'], 
                              ['1A', '4A']]})
```

I would start by splitting the associated modules into separate columns.

```
In [2]: modules = df['Associate Modules'].apply(Series)
In [3]: modules.index = df['Address']
In [4]: modules
Out[4]: 
          0   1    2
Address             
1000     1A  2A   3A
1001     2A  4A   5A
1002     1A  4A  NaN
```

Then stack the DataFrame, and drop our dummy columns index.

```
In [5]: result = modules.stack()
In [6]: result.index = result.index.get_level_values(0)

In [7]: result
Out[7]: 
Address
1000       1A
1000       2A
1000       3A
1001       2A
1001       4A
1001       5A
1002       1A
1002       4A
```

If you want Address as a proper column instead of an index, use the `reset_index()` method. There is probably a sleeker way, but isn't too ugly.